# C shared memory using fork()

Tags: c, fork, shared-memory

So here's the situation, I have to develop a multi-player game using c in unix. Now i created the sockets and the server and client are communicating ok. Now this game includes a board, so each client has its own 2d array of 100x40, and they are sending the x and y position using the read/write (which is working ok too) to the server.

Now, in the server, I'm using fork() so that new clients can join the game. In the child's section, I'm receiving the x and y position. Now my question is, how can I store the x and y position to a "global" board[100][40] found in the server (so I may check for collisions etc). The difficulty I'm finding is that each child is having its own version of the board since I'm using fork(), and I'm only updating the board of that particular child. I would like that each time the client sends it x and y position, I place them in the board found in server.

I've read that I would need to use some sort of IPC, like shared memory, but can't figure it out. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: This answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327349/how-can-i-share-memory-between-parent-child-process-that-free-the-memory-automat

Comment: Why not use threads instead of processes?

Comment: it was strongly recommended by our lecturer to use fork instead as its much easier and not need to worry about race conditions etc.

Comment: The only reason you would not worry about race conditions is if they are not sharing memory which fork does not share memory by default which is why it avoids race conditions. As soon as you want a global memory with fork, race conditions can occur just like threads

Comment: That's true. In cases where you can use threads communications, just use it over IPC. You'll make your life much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Use the shared memory API calls: `shmget`, `shmat`, `shmdet`, ... [Example code](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html#SECTION002730000000000000000).

If the server is simple, you could use threads. With threads you can simply access the same global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use threads instead of processes because they're lightweight, i.e., they have a much less overhead. The idea is to allocate the board on the heap so that it's shared among all threads in this process.

When there is a new player joining in the game, [create a new thread](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html).

When the player needs to update their board info, the shared board should be accessed in a mutual-exclusive way to prevent [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), such as:

```
void UpdateBoard(int X, int Y)
{
  // e.g., pthread_mutex_lock
  Enter critical section
  ..
  Update board(X, Y)
  ..
  // e.g., pthread_mutex_unlock
  Leave critical section
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a database would solve all your locking / concurrency problems.